# How to sort a column in sql based on value B where values in fields are in format A-B-C. I w

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to sort a column in a table where the value in the column is in format `00000197-001-00001` and so on.

I have tried with query

`select * from <table name> where <condition> order by column name.`

Values are sorted till `00000197-099-001`. But after this, the value I am getting is *00000197-**1000**-001* in my list instead *00000197-**100**-001*.

**The result I am getting:**

00000197-097-000001

00000197-098-000001

00000197-**099**-000001

00000197-**1000**-000001

00000197-**100**-000001

00000197-1001-000001

00000197-1002-000001

00000197-1003-000001

00000197-1004-000001

00000197-1005-000001

00000197-1006-000001

00000197-1007-000001

00000197-1008-000001

00000197-1009-000001

00000197-**1010**-000001

00000197-**101**-000001

00000197-**1011**-000001

00000197-1012-000001

**Expected Result:**

00000197-097-000001

00000197-098-000001

00000197-**099**-000001

00000197-**100**-000001

00000197-101-000001

.

.

.

00000197-**999**-000001

00000197-**1000**-000001

00000197-1001-000001

00000197-1002-000001

00000197-1003-000001

.

.

.

Please suggest the solution. 
Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your sample data, you  can do:

```
order by len(column1), column1
```

This idea will work in any database, although the length function might be `length()` rather than `len()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable1
 ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(MyCol1, CHARINDEX('-', MyCol1, 0) + 1, 100), 0, CHARINDEX('-', substring(MyCol1, CHARINDEX('-', MyCol1, 0) + 1, 100), 0)) as int)
```

This works for every string of any length in format X-Y-Z.

Comment: This doesn't help me, I am getting results now as below:

00000197-097-000001

00000197-098-000001

00000197-**099**-000001

00000197-**1007**-000001

00000197-**1003**-000001

00000197-**1009**-000001

00000197-**100**-000001

00000197-1002-000001
00000197-1004-000001
00000197-1008-000001
00000197-1001-000001
00000197-1005-000001
00000197-1000-000001
00000197-1006-000001
00000197-1016-000001
00000197-1018-000001
00000197-1010-000001

Comment: Yes, I didn't see the numbers above 1000 in your sample data. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is also not working for me.. I am getting errors in this query.

For CAST I am getting: CAST function required 1 argument(s).
For Select( near CAST): Incorrect syntax near Select.

Also I have provided column name in place of @MyCol, and I am getting invalid column name error.

Also in last there is one extra closing bracket in present.

Comment: Thers 'as int' at the end (and I had @ char in the middle), try now